# How to send data to a server using AJAX?

Tags: javascript, ajax

We know how to get data from a server using ajax's GET method but can we also send data to a server using ajax? If so, how do we do it?

Also, can you show how to do it without jquery?

Comment: It's the same, you send data and receive a response even if the response is just in the http code

Comment: to send data using get, use the url : somurl/?x=1&z=2

Answer (score 0):

```
var xhr = null;
if (typeof XMLHttpRequest != "undefined") {
  xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
} else if (ActiveXObject) {
  var aVersions = [
    "Msxml2.XMLHttp.5.0", 
    "Msxml2.XMLHttp.4.0",
    "Msxml2.XMLHttp.3.0", 
    "Msxml2.XMLHttp", 
    "Microsoft.XMLHttp"
  ];
  for (var i = 0; i < aVersions.length; i++) {
    try {
      xhr = new ActiveXObject(aVersions[i]);
      break;
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }
}
if(xhr) {
  xhr.open('POST', 'your server url', true);
  xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
    if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
      if(xhr.status === 200) {
        console.log(xhr.responseText);
      }
    }
  }
  xhr.send();
} else {
  console.log('cannot create xhr!');
}
```